# OpenShift Origin: Failed to execute: 'control start' when creating a Ruby 1.9/1.8 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openshift-origin

When I attempt to create a Ruby application within OpenShift Origin I get the following error:

```
Starting Ruby cartridge
Failed to execute: 'control start' for /var/lib/openshift/540f759e19c94b7916000064/ruby
```

Following this up in the logs I can see the following, can anybody point me in the right direction?

Latest version of Origin, installed from oo-installer.

```
2014-09-09 17:48:14.741 [INFO ] Parameters: {"cartridges"=>["ruby-1.9"], "domain_id"=>"development", "gear_profile"=>"small", "initial_git_branch"=>"", "initial_git_url"=>"", "name"=>"ruby", "scale"=>"false"} (pid:7765)
2014-09-09 17:48:36.486 [ERROR] Failed to execute: 'control start' for /var/lib/openshift/540f759e19c94b7916000064/ruby (pid:7765)
2014-09-09 17:48:36.487 [ERROR] /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-msg-broker-mcollective-1.26.1.1/lib/openshift/mcollective_application_container_proxy.rb:2763:in `parse_result'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-msg-broker-mcollective-1.26.1.1/lib/openshift/mcollective_application_container_proxy.rb:2944:in `run_cartridge_command'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-msg-broker-mcollective-1.26.1.1/lib/openshift/mcollective_application_container_proxy.rb:846:in `post_configure_component'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-controller-1.26.3.1/app/models/gear.rb:196:in `post_configure_component'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-controller-1.26.3.1/app/pending_ops_models/post_configure_comp_op.rb:12:in `execute'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-controller-1.26.3.1/app/models/pending_app_op_group.rb:104:in `block in execute'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-controller-1.26.3.1/app/models/pending_app_op_group.rb:94:in `each'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-controller-1.26.3.1/app/models/pending_app_op_group.rb:94:in `execute'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-controller-1.26.3.1/app/models/application.rb:1719:in `run_jobs'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-controller-1.26.3.1/app/models/application.rb:824:in `block in add_cartridges'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-controller-1.26.3.1/app/models/lock.rb:62:in `run_in_app_lock'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-controller-1.26.3.1/app/models/application.rb:801:in `add_cartridges'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-controller-1.26.3.1/app/models/application.rb:654:in `add_initial_cartridges'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-controller-1.26.3.1/app/controllers/applications_controller.rb:170:in `create'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:481:in `block in _run__4204384996818884849__process_action__2449202845933876977__callbacks'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:215:in `block in _conditional_callback_around_519'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/openshift-origin-controller-1.26.3.1/lib/openshift/controller/action_log.rb:80:in `set_logged_request'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:214:in `_conditional_callback_around_519'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__4204384996818884849__process_action__2449202845933876977__callbacks'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/mongoid-3.0.21/lib/rack/mongoid/middleware/identity_map.rb:34:in `block in call'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/mongoid-3.0.21/lib/mongoid/unit_of_work.rb:39:in `unit_of_work'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/mongoid-3.0.21/lib/rack/mongoid/middleware/identity_map.rb:34:in `call'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:339:in `call'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__2514728056779631320__call__364474079927790510__callbacks'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:143:in `pass'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:155:in `invalidate'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:71:in `call!'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:97:in `process_request'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:521:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:274:in `main_loop'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:206:in `start_request_handler'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:171:in `block in handle_spawn_application'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:470:in `safe_fork'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:166:in `handle_spawn_application'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:129:in `start'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `block in spawn_rack_application'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `block in synchronize'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:244:in `spawn_rack_application'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:137:in `spawn_application'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.21/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:102:in `<main>' (pid:7765)
2014-09-09 17:48:36.487 [ERROR] Encountered error during execute 'Failed to execute: 'control start' for /var/lib/openshift/540f759e19c94b7916000064/ruby
' (pid:7765)
2014-09-09 17:48:38.526 [INFO ] Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 23785ms (Views: 1.5ms) (pid:7765)
```